# Find ${\partial z\over \partial x}$ and ${\partial z \over \partial y}$ for $xy + yz = xz$

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

I'm currently learning how to use partial differentiation. Can someone give me a hint?

find  ${\partial z\over \partial x}$ and ${\partial z \over \partial y}$ for $xy + yz = xz$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $x$ and $y$ are independent variables, differentiating both sides with respect to $x$ using product rule, we get,
\begin{equation*}
y+y\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} = z+x\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}
\end{equation*}
Solving this we get the desired result for $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}$. Similarly for $y$.

You can also check that answer obtained this way is correct answer by explicit differentiation:
\begin{align}
&z=\dfrac{xy}{x-y}\\
\implies &\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} = -\dfrac{y^2}{(x-y)^2}
\end{align}

And answer obtained above is
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \dfrac{y-z}{x-y}
\end{equation}

Substituting $z=\dfrac{xy}{x-y}$ in above equation, we get,
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} = -\dfrac{y^2}{(x-y)^2}
\end{equation}

Comment: Note that if $y$ and $x$ are not independent variables, then there would be $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ term as well.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$Calculate
the *differential* of the entire equation
$$\eqalign{
0 &= d(xy + yz - xz) \\
  &= d(xy) + d(yz) - d(xz) \\
  &= (x\,dy + y\,dx) + (y\,dz + z\,dy) - (x\,dz + z\,dx) \\
(x-y)\,dz &= (y-z)\,dx + (x+z)\,dy \\
}$$
Holding $x$ constant (i.e. setting $\,dx=0$) yields
$$\eqalign{
(x-y)\,dz  &= (x+z)\,dy \quad\implies\quad  \p{z}{y} = \frac{x+z}{x-y} \\
}$$
While holding $y$ constant ($dy=0$) yields
$$\eqalign{
(x-y)\,dz  &= (y-z)\,dx \quad\implies\quad  \p{z}{x} = \frac{y-z}{x-y} \\
}$$